# JavaScript Redirect with hash/pound/#

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

So I need to open tabs from my website to other websites using JavaScript and jQuery (I cannot use an `<a>` tag as a requirement). The links come from the database, so I set the title of the object the user clicks to the link and then redirect them when they click it, and I have code that does this alright:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var RedirectCount = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".ResultRow").click(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("title") != "") 
            {
                window.open($(this).attr("title"), "Program" + RedirectCount, "");
                RedirectCount = RedirectCount + 1;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So this works great, except that many of the URL's have `#` signs in them which is supposed to open up a specific tab on the destination page.  This works on Firefox, but IE 8 removes the `#` tag before the second tab opens. I also tried recoding the URL using JavaScript's built in `URLEncode` function, ASP.NET's `URLEncode` function, and simply replacing `#` signs with `%20`, none perform the correct action.

I do not have access to other browsers, and I've been googling the problem for the last half hour without finding an answer, so what I'm looking for are the answers to these two questions:

1. Is there any other way to open a new tab that will always work with a `#` besides window.open or an `<a target="_blank">` tag?
2. How many browsers don't perform this action correctly (especially Google Chrome)?  Has the issue been fixed in IE9+?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce, but this test case does work for me on IE9 with IE8 emulated: http://jsfiddle.net/yugq7/2/. Is this perhaps not what you mean?

Comment: I have IE8, I am not emulating IE8, so perhaps the bug is simply an oversight in the emulation.  Good to know the problem is not present in IE9.

Comment: The emulation is there to test in a IE8 scenario, so it should have all bugs normal IE8 also has. Does the fiddle not work for you?

Comment: Actually, I see the problem now, Its something to do with the .NET VS environment, when I run my code on the test server, it redirects fine, but when I run it in debug mode it doesn't pass the # along.  Your suggestion did lead to the answer.

Comment: Sorry to pick nits, but `#` should be replaced with `%23`, not `%20`.

Comment: a good point, I didn't want to go look it up again, but when I did look it up on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp I used %23 and it did not work.  Points for thoroughness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that Visual Studio interferes with the way in which IE8 runs the JavaScript code, and that the code listed in the question will in fact work properly when running under normal conditions.  I do not know why, nor do I feel that it is important enough to figure out why, perhaps in a few years someone may find this answer out and add it to the comments below.